ReactNative 0.76.2 Expo SDK 52 Unimplemented component <RNDateTimePicker>
I am getting Unimplemented component <RNDateTimePicker> for @react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker after upgrading to Expo SDK 52
Does anyone know what might be causing it?
It used to work fine for Expo SDK 51
react-native: 0.76.2

expo: ~52.0.17

@react-native-community/datetimepicker: 8.2.0



I ended up using the lib react-native-date-picker

I get this issue, in my iOS simulator"Unimplemented component: " while using this packages:
{
"react-native": "0.76.1",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^18.0.0",
}


@ArefinDe please see my answer to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79309741/4008161

I couldn't make it work so I ended up using: https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker
